# Google Maps Hash value not accepted (Convert SHA1 to MD5?)

Tags: android

I've followed the steps delineated in Lee's android book on generating an MD5 fingerprint:

At a command prompt, I navigated to: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

I then entered:
keytool.exe ... C:\Users\Clay.android\debug.keystore
... (etc. - from p. 112 of "Beginning Android Tablet Application Development" by Wei-Meng Lee)

It generates a code like this:

:
CC:AB:1E:GD:E8:18:29:3A:25:3D:B9:19:23:F1:10:3C:15:14:CF:2B

When I enter this at http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html, it takes me to another page that tells me that the entered value is invalid ("The fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint")

Note: I did not add the "" portion. I tried it with and without the colon separators.

As it says it is MD5 that is needed, and the values is apparently SHA1, do I need to convert this SHA1 to MD5? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate the key with the JDK6 keytool.

**EDIT** after answer was accepted:
As stated in the other answer, you can also use JDK7 keytool with the `-v` parameter.

Comment: That generated an MD5 just fine, thanks. The link to download JDK 6 is: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u29-download-513648.html

Answer (score 10):

If you use JDK 7 keytool, add the -v option. It will include the MD5 fingerprint in it's output.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/sha1
Put your sha1(fingerprint) value into the textbox and the tool will automatically convert it into MD5 Fingerprint. Hope this will solve your issue.